# What would the equivalent of this be in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hello just wondering if anyone knows what this would be in jQuery.

```
function remix(random_num){
    var limit = images.length;
    var random_num1 = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
    var random_num2 = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
    var random_num3 = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
    document.getElementById("layer1").src = images[random_num1];
    document.getElementById("layer2").src = images[random_num2];
    document.getElementById("layer3").src = images[random_num3];
}
```

Comment: It should work "in jquery" the way it is. Are you looking for the [docs on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)?

Comment: Removed salutation: " Thanks in advance.", don't do it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this would be better

```
function remix(random_num){
  var limit = images.length;
  for(var i = 0; i< 3;i++){
   var random = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
   $("#layer"+i).attr("src", images[random])
  }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Replace all your

```
document.getElementById("layerN").src = images[random_numN];
```

with the

```
$("#layerN").attr("src", images[random_numN]);
```

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
// give your images a common class name, then:
function remix(){
    var images = $('.images');
    images.each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[0 | images.length * Math.random() ]);
    });
}
```

If you don't want to give them a common class name, change `$('.images')` to `$('#layer1,#layer2,#layer3')`

Answer (score 1):

```
function remix(random_num){
    var limit = images.length;
    $("#layer1").attr("src", images[Math.floor(limit * Math.random())]);
    $("#layer2").attr("src", images[Math.floor(limit * Math.random())]);
    $("#layer3").attr("src", images[Math.floor(limit * Math.random())]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below

```
function remix(random_num){
        var limit = images.length;
        var random_num1 = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
        var random_num2 = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
        var random_num3 = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
        $("#layer1").attr("src",images[random_num1]);
        $("#layer2").attr("src", images[random_num2]);
        $("#layer3").attr("src",images[random_num3]);
    }
```

Comment: You have to use `$("#...").attr("src", newValue);`. `$("#...").attr("src") = newValue;` doesn't work.

Comment: He's not setting them to a random number, he's choosing a random index from the `images` array.

Comment: @Arxisos agree Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The only thing jQuery can do here is help you set the `src` attributes.

```
$('#layer1').attr('src', images[random_num1]);
$('#layer2').attr('src', images[random_num2]);
$('#layer3').attr('src', images[random_num3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function remix(){
    var limit = images.length;
    $([1,2,3]).each(function(idx){
       $('#layer' + idx).attr('src', images[Math.floor(limit * Math.random())]);
    });
}
```